# Three valued logic with nullable bool?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, logic, nullable

I have a easy control with *nothing chosen at begin* and user decide to set *yes* or *no*. All in all a standard example for three valued logic.

So my first thought was to take nullable bool to persist. Normally this would leads me to some annoying `if (var == null) { ... }` (or something similar).

Second thought brings me to Enums.

```
public enum Selection
{
   Yes,
   No,
   NotChoosenYet
}
```

In my context this brings to some enum to bool converts, but this is not a show-stopper.

All in all I tend to chose the "Enum-way", because is more readable.
I searched SO for a while but can't find a question which brings me a sept forward.

Is there a better way which I do not consider yet? Maybe a standard .Net-Type which can make thinks more easy?

Comment: Enums will certainly be more readable if you don't use meaningful names for variables when using booleans and such. What's annoying about a nullity check, though? It's standard procedure.

Comment: So how is the `enum` better than `bool?` ? You will have some `if`s anyway.

Comment: I know a lot of code which have so many if (var == null) checks that code in self becomes more confused (or large) than should. Maybe thats the reason way I'm not a fan of null.

Comment: @Micha Yet `if (selection == Selection.NotChoosenYet) { ... ` is longer. And a `switch` even more verbose.

Comment: http://wpf.2000things.com/2011/07/29/353-binding-a-three-state-checkbox-to-a-nullable-bool/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd stick with ENUMS.

My three reasons that come to mind in a second:

1. It's more readable.
2. You avoid null poiters and unnecessary null-check code.
3. You can add another option (eg. 'Ask me later') without refactoring your whole source.

Comment: In my (special) context your arguments are the most suitable.

Answer (score 2):

I would stick with the nullable boolean, as this is how you will represent it in the database.

Either NULL, Yes or No.

From [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

> Nullable types are instances of the Nullable struct. A nullable type
>   can represent the correct range of values for its underlying value
>   type, plus an additional null value. For example, a Nullable,
>   pronounced "Nullable of Int32," can be assigned any value from
>   -2147483648 to 2147483647, or it can be assigned the null value. A Nullable can be assigned the values true false, or null. **The
>   ability to assign null to numeric and Boolean types is especially
>   useful when you are dealing with databases and other data types that
>   contain elements that may not be assigned a value. For example, a
>   Boolean field in a database can store the values true or false, or it
>   may be undefined.**

Also from [Using Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx)

> For an example of when you might use a nullable type, consider how an
>   ordinary Boolean variable can have two values: true and false. There
>   is no value that signifies "undefined". In many programming
>   applications, most notably database interactions, variables can occur
>   in an undefined state. For example, a field in a database may contain
>   the values true or false, but it may also contain no value at all.
>   Similarly, reference types can be set to null to indicate that they
>   are not initialized.

Comment: Thats no problem. In the end (before saving in db) user have to choose yes or no.

Comment: Thanks for adding the MSDN-infos (+1). Interesting - considering to that nullable bool would be the "microsoft-choice". In my case I do not use database to store the data, but I will consider this.

Answer (score 1):

I would mimic the way it is stored in the database. If it is null, true and false in the db, then use null, yes, no in the c#-code. It is undecided, yes, no in the db then use the enum in the c#-code. Simply because this would be easier for the next guy.

If I choose between these two, the enum looks better.